# exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 3)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Boa noite pessoal.

Cara odeio esse erro e não faço ideia de como concertar. Estou fechando a conexão com o banco depois de cada requerimento dele mas mesmo assim continua.

Estou usando PHP.

Alguém sabe como concertar isso?

**exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 3)**

Comment: Pode existir alguma query tomando muito tempo, assim atingindo o máximo de conexões simultâneas. Verifique no `my.cnf`e então dê um `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. Se o número de processos for igual ou proximo do definido no my.cnf, este é o motivo. Uma coisa que pode resolver, além de expandir o limite e alterar o `ISOLATION LEVEL`, dessa forma talvez mais querys podem ser executadas "por vez" entre outras coisas.

Comment: Onde acesso esse my.cnf? Porque isso acontece quando vou acessar online, no local acesso normal.

Comment: Isso depende de seu servidor. Você precisa ter acesso ao `root`, primeiramente. Geralmente é `/etc/my.cnf` ou `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Edite o `max_user_connections`.

Comment: Estou em uma hospedagem gratuita da hostinger, pra testar o projeto

Comment: Hospedagens compartilhadas (e alguns VPS) não permitem alterar isso. Neste caso recomendo que migre para servidores em cloud menores, como a DigitalOcean e também Linode. Eles custam 5 dólares e 10 dólares por mês, respectivamente, e é cobrado por hora, cancelando antes pagará apenas o que usou. Facilmente encontra cupons de desconto e referencias que ainda de garante um saldo de 10 dólares. A Linode ainda oferece reembolso caso não consiga utilizar. Existem outras opções como Rackspace (sendo mais cara, no minimo 75 dolares por mês), assim como a Amazon e Google Cloud. Acho a melhor opção.

Comment: é, realmente isso é problema de onde vc hospeda seu site, etc..
Não é nem questão de fechar a conexão. Aff kkkk. Valeu hein cara